# C# Call or Click <a href=#myref ID=MyRef>MyLink</a> from code behind

Tags: c#

I would like to do this.

```
<asp:Button OnClick="MyCode" ID="Button1" runat="server"/>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="ButtonLink" href="#menu">
    <img src="images/create.png"/>
</asp:LinkButton>


protected void MyCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Run my update script here
    ButtonLink.Click();
}
```

However I need this to be simulated on the client side, no code behind for that action.

Comment: I don't get what "this" is in your last line. Do you want to click the Button or the LinkButton ? How is the matter related to the <a href... in the question title ? Please provide more detail and context (re-read your own question and ask yourself "can someone who has no clue what I'm talking about understand my problem?", it helps).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to trigger a `click` event on a link through JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('<%= ButtonLink.ClientID %>').click();
```